# executable python file sys not accepting '(' character

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to write a python file that takes command line input and performs some actions. The input will consist of a-z, [, ], ( and ). I made the following program just to check that I could keep going:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

print str(sys.argv)
```

I did `chmod +x program` and tried calling `./program qwerty (abc) [hi]` and it returned:

-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Is there any way of changing **the program** so that it accepted parentheses in arguments?

Note: I have also tried placing square brackets before parentheses and it returns the same error.

Comment: `()` has special meaning to shell - it invokes the enclosed command in a subshell.  Enclose your strings in double quotes to remove the special meaning - `./program qwerty "(abc)" "[hi]"`

Comment: I'm following a spec and won't be able to change the input, edited question above.

Comment: It's failing in the shell before **the program** runs, so no, you can't change it in the program.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing the script can do about shell syntax when invoking the script. The shell parses the command line first. You have to escape or quote characters that have special meaning in the shell (which includes most punctuation characters):

```
./program qwerty \(abc\) '[hi]'
```